# Oracle SQL: sum( case when then quantity else 0 END) OVER (partition by...) = can't get right GROUP BY statement

Tags: sql, group-by, oracle11g, windowing

I'm trying to select several different sums, one of them being `OVER (Partition by column_also_in_select_plan)`.

However I cannot seem to ever be able to get the `GROUP BY` statement right.

Example:

```
Select 1, 2, 3, sum(4) over (partition by 3), sum(case when 6 = etc...) 
FROM table
Where filters
GROUP BY ?
```

Thanks for any tips :)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really make much sense to be doing aggregation *and* using window functions at the same time, so I'm not surprised you're confused. In the above example, you probably want to move the windowing to an outer query, that is:

```
select 1, 2, 3, sum(sum4) over(partition by 3), ...
from (
      select 1, 2, 3, sum(4) as sum4
      from table
      where filters
      group by 1, 2, 3
) x
```